# Creating a script that waits for a start/stop to finish

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, tomcat

I'm trying to create a build script for an application that needs to be deployed to a remote server. The script needs to shutdown the running instance of tomcat, do some work (copying/moving files), start the tomcat instance back up, and then repeat the procedure on a second node.

The individual steps are pretty straightforward. What I'm struggling with is controlling the timing. I want to make sure that the tomcat application server has finished shutting down before the script starts moving files. I also want to make sure that the server has finished starting up before I start the shutdown on the second instance.

Is there any way to do this in a shell script other than just setting manual 'wait' timers?

Comment: Is your `tomcat` run as `systemd`-service?

Comment: @FelixJN I should have mentioned that but yes it is running as a service.

Answer (score 0):

One may use `systemctl` for a query of the service status:

```
systemctl is-active tomcat.service
```

From [the manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html)

> is-active PATTERN…
>
> Check whether any of the specified units are active (i.e. running). Returns an exit code 0 if at least one is active, or non-zero otherwise. Unless --quiet is specified, this will also print the current unit state to standard output.

Note that the same manual states that relying on the exit status of `systemctl status <unit>` explcitly is considered "imperfect".

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't quite do what I want. I tested it out and the is-active status changes as soon as the start or stop command is received. I want something that will actually wait until the startup or shutdown completes.

Comment: I see your problem. As for the stopping part, using [`ExitType=cgroup`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) in the unit might help. For starting there is a [watchdog](https://github.com/tranmh/systemd-watchdog-tomcat) that allows using `Type=notify`. Neither tested, so mere suggestions and hints.